# Linear Algebra Transformations Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A be a basis of vector space V and B be a basis of vector space W.  Let there also be a linear transformation T:V→W.

What does the following notation signify?
$$[T]_B,_A$$

The notation appeared very briefly in the chapter about similarity in my textbook but I am not quite understanding what is being asked of me when I see this notation.

Answer (score 0):

$[T]_{B,A}$ denotes the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $A$ of $V$ and $B$ of $W$.